# Getting ??? while putting non-latin data to mysql via Nifi

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi

While inserting Arabic characters(non-latin) in MySQL using PutDatabaseRecord processor of Nifi the characters are getting replaced by "???????"

After insertion, the Arabic String is getting replaced with ??????.I have created the MySQL table using utf8.

```
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE  utf8_general_ci
```

Please let me know if someone got the resolution for the same. Using Sqoop also, the Arabic characters are getting replaced by "????????".

Comment: While I am no MySQL expert, this certainly looks like something is translating higher-code-points to ? characters because it is being projected into an 8-bit code page. But it is hard to say, because the question is low on details. If you include more specifics (complete DDL for table, relevant system settings, what does table contents look like on admin tool vs query tool, sample code for insertion, sample code for query, etc) you have a better chance of getting an answer -- give us something concrete to go on.

Comment: please provide jdbc url and driver

Comment: How have you determined these characters are "?????"? It could be tool that is displaying the characters that is causing the problem. Remember there are two distinct cases here: how the data is accepted and represented in the table, and how that table data is fetched and (in this case) displayed. You need to show with an [edit] how you are doing both of these things.

Comment: Because after exploring the same data to Hive I am getting ?????????? (junk records)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with Sqoop, where I have added the below part in the connection string

```
useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```